# What is wrong with my function? Giving me a blank output

Tags: python-3.x, function, math, output

```
def get_nearest_multiple(minnum, factor):
    """
    function get_nearest_multiple will calculate the nearest multiple that is greater than the min. value,
    Parameters are the minimum value and factor,
    Will return the ans - the nearest multiple
    """
ans = 0
x = 1
while ans < minnum:
    if minnum == 0:
        ans = 0
    else:
        ans = x * factor
        x += 1
    return ans

get_nearest_multiple(0, 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_nearest_multiple(0, 1)
```

Can't seem to figure out why my function doesn't print out anything. The output doesn't even show up as an error. Just blank.

Comment: Which line is supposed to print something?

Comment: indent the function correctly, and do print(get_nearest_multiple(0, 1))

Comment: additionally, your while loop returns None in this case so you should inspect your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code do you have a `print()` statement which is required to produce an output in the console